# What happens if I get all 5 cards the same?

Tags: rules, hand

So, let's say when the dealer first deals the cards, I get two 9's (any color, shape) and then on the table, by the end of the game (the river), there are 3 more 9's. What happens now? Is there a rank in poker if all 5 cards are the same number? Does this happen? I mean, theoretically it could with the number of cards involved, but statistically, how likely is it and what happens in such a case? Is the player with 5 same numbered cards, the obvious winner?

Very very new to poker. This happened to me in an online game, I got two 9's from the dealer, got two more 9's on the table but there was surely a chance I'd have gone 5 on 5.

Comment: No rank of all 5 the same for a reason

Comment: Op is assuming two decks are used in poker (from comment on one of the answers). Only one deck is used in poker, therefore five of a kind with a 52 card deck is impossible. If the deck is foul and you make 5 of a kind it is a misdeal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a real question, due to the OP not understanding that poker is only played with one deck. If the OP now understands there is only one deck,  he no longer has a question. The question or any answer is of no value to anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

A normal deck of cards contains 4 cards of equal value, not 5.
What you describe here is just not possible, poker or not.

Comment: But, poker is played with two card decks right?

Comment: @D437 No poker is only played with one deck.

Answer (score 0):

If you, as a player, spot an irregularity of the deck (5 of a rank, 2 indentical cards, mismatched back, joker in a game that doesn't use it, etc.) You are obligated to tell the dealer/floor/other players immediately. The hand will be voided, and all money bet to that point returned. Failure to do so is considered cheating, and if detected may result in your ejection from the game.